# jQuery live preview form load directly after mysql query

Tags: jquery, forms, mysqli, live-preview

I found a great jQuery Code on this page and used it on my site. It works great.
A form and a live Preview with the jQuery. But now when i want to update the db and open the form again it will correctly put the text in the formfields, but the preview only starts after i click in and out of the field. How can i force my function to start the preview directly after the mysqli query?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var commentNode = $('#lp-comment'),
        contactNode = $('#lp-contact'),
        contact = $('#contact'),
        website = $('#website');

    //comment...easy
    $('#live-preview-form input, #live-preview-form textarea').bind('blur keyup',function() {
        //comment
        commentNode.text($('#comment').val());
        commentNode.html($('#lp-comment').html().replace(/\n/g,'<br />'));
        contactNode.text(contact.val() + ' says:');

    });
});
```

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var commentNode = $('#lp-comment'),
  contactNode = $('#lp-contact'),
  contact = $('#contact'),
  website = $('#website');
 
 //comment...easy
 $('#live-preview-form input, #live-preview-form textarea').bind('blur keyup',function() {
  //comment
  commentNode.text($('#comment').val());
  commentNode.html($('#lp-comment').html().replace(/\n/g,'<br />'));
  contactNode.text(contact.val() + ' says:');
  
  

  
  
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="live-preview-form" class="lp-block field">
 <input name="contact" class="input" placeholder="Kontaktperson" type="text" id="contact" value ="<?php echo $contact ?>" required />
 </div>

<div id="live-preview-display" class="lp-block">
 
 <div id="lp-contact"></div>
 <div id="lp-comment"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to refresh the preview when the page is reloaded, or any other time the data is updated. You might consider creating a function to update the preview so that it can be called on `$(document).ready` and in `onblur` and `onkeyup`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  updatePreview();

  $('#live-preview-form input, #live-preview-form textarea').bind('blur keyup',updatePreview);
});

function updatePreview(){
  var commentNode = $('#lp-comment'),
      contactNode = $('#lp-contact'),
      contact = $('#contact');

  commentNode.text($('#comment').val());
  commentNode.html($('#lp-comment').html().replace(/\n/g,'<br />'));
  contactNode.text(contact.val() + ' says:');

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="live-preview-form" class="lp-block field">
 <input name="contact" class="input" placeholder="Kontaktperson" type="text" id="contact" value ="<?php echo $contact ?>" required />
 </div>

<div id="live-preview-display" class="lp-block">
 
 <div id="lp-contact"></div>
 <div id="lp-comment"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Did exactly what i'm was looking for.